# Why `Project Reactor` source code is so large in a class file

Tags: coding-style, project-reactor

when I read the source code of Project Reactor, I find there are so many lines in each class file which looks like not code clean and not so readable, e.g. almost ten thousand lines in `Flux.class`. Does anyone know what's the reason for `Project Reactor` to write code as this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat these "general rules" with care. A large number of lines in a file is often an indication of bad coding practice, but it isn't *necessarily* so. I'm not part of the reactor team (or any team at pivotal for that matter!) but there's a few semi-obvious reasons why it's this way:

- Have a look at [the source code here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.java) and scroll through - you'll find the *vast* majority of those lines are comments, so the *actual* LoC count is way less. That's incredibly important, the Javadoc for the core reactor classes is some of the best I've come across in a third party library.
- Lots of methods on the one class (in this case at least) makes it easier to use. There's quite simply lots of operations one may want to perform on a `Flux`. Those could be spread out over multiple classes or sub-objects, but that's a pain in the rear end in real-world use compared to just finding the method you need on the one class.
- Similarly for static factory methods - there's quite a few of these and they're also all available on the `Flux` directly. Once upon a time these may have been spread out into multiple factory classes, but that's fallen out of fashion in the last few years (rightly so IMHO.)

Could the reactor team reduce the number of lines in the Flux class? Sure. But what would that achieve? For a popular library that's already quite difficult for "traditional" Java devs to get their head around quickly, making it more cumbersome to use just to reduce the line count here and there would be a very poor trade-off.

Comment: Hi Michael,  thank you for your detailed answer. However, your answer just explains the current phenomenon is reasonable and not bad to some extent. Another thing I want to know is that —— is there any benefit or advantage when the reactor team choose this code style at begining? For example, there is a lot of static classes in the `FluxSink.class`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @高春华 The advantage of the large `Flux` class with lots of documentation & methods in one place is that it's easier to use for those consuming the library. I'm not sure what you mean about `FluxSink`, [I can't see any static classes](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.java).

Comment: I'm sorry that I said it wrongly. It shoud be there is a lot of static classes in [`FluxCreate`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxCreate.java) which extends the interface `FluxSink`. In additon, I'm able to understand the advantage with lots of documentation, but can't understand the advantage about the lots of methods in one place. Currently it makes me hard to find code when i use the scroll bar in IDE. Could you help me explain it more about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the authors are trying to imitate functional style of programming, where user of a library can call functions (procedures, methods), but cannot create new objects using constructors. Of course, every asynchronous program is a graph of objects, and it is impossible to avoid creation of new objects. The authors decided to make most of the classes inaccessible to users and instead provided factory methods to create objects. See, for example, following piece of code:

> ```
>     if (sources.length == 1) {
>         Publisher<? extends T> source = sources[0];
>         if (source instanceof Fuseable) {
>             return onAssembly(new FluxMapFuseable<>(from(source),
>                     v -> combinator.apply(new Object[]{v})));
>         }
>         return onAssembly(new FluxMap<>(from(source),
>                 v -> combinator.apply(new Object[]{v})));
>     }
>     return onAssembly(new FluxCombineLatest<>(sources,
>             combinator, Queues.get(prefetch), prefetch));
> ```

The classes FluxMapFuseable, FluxMap, FluxCombineLatest all are package-private. User cannot instantiate them, and library authors have to code creation objects of that classes in additional methods.

If the library were written in object-oriented style, then the authors would have provide user with a minimal set of core classes and let user freely extend them and combine objects in any suitable way, and get rid of the burden to "cover all combinations of all capabilities", as Doug Lea wrote at his [post to concurrency-interest forum](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Reactive-Streams-Utility-API-tt14647.html#a14668).

BTW I wrote an asynchronous library in OO style (DF4J, Dataflow for Java), and it is orders of magnitude shorter than Project Reactor or RxJava. Of course it does not provide everything mainstream libraries provide, but it has some unique features like ability to construct asynchronous procedure calls with arbitrary number of asynchronous parameters.